# madvise: not understood

Tags: c, linux, ram, mmap

## CONTEXT:

I run on an old laptop. I only just have 128Mo ram free on 512Mo total. No money to buy more ram.

I use `mmap` to help me circumvent this issue and it works quite well.
C code.
Debian 64 bits.

## PROBLEM:

Besides all my efforts, I am running out of memory pretty quick right know and I would like to know if I could release the mmaped regions I read to free my ram.

I read that `madvise` could help, especially the option `MADV_SEQUENTIAL`.

But I don't quite understand the whole picture.

## THE NEED:

To be able to free mmaped allocated memory after the region is read so that it doesn't fill my whole ram with large files. I will not read it soon so it is garbage to me. It is pointless to keep it in ram.

Update: I am not done with the file so don't want to call `munmap`. I have other stuffs to do with it but in another regions of it. Random reads.

Comment: **Why** do you use mmap+madvise? Maybe your task could be accomplished by reading one character at a time, or one line at the time. What is the goal of your program?

Comment: My read is random in the file. And I have understood that MADV_SEQUENTIAL may help to free the resources. So I would like to know more about it. That is it:)

Comment: Unless you are using MAP_PRIVATE (which you should not) no resources are used by mmap (except for the fd and the pagetables). Pages will be faulted-in when needed and kicked out by the LRU bufferchain if unused for too long. MADV_SEQUENTIAL is not needed (and maybe even a bad idea)

Comment: Ok, so what I want is to accelerate the way LRU will "garbage collect". Because when I switch from one app to another, my system is not responsive anymore.

Comment: There is no way to improve on the LRU (scheduler) : given enough memory pressure, paging ("swapping") just happens. Reduce the number of running apps to reduce the memory usage is all you can do.

Comment: If your reading is random, then MADV_SEQUENTIAL is probably of limited use. MADV_SEQUENTIAL tells the system that you expect to read the file sequentially, not randomly - this enables read-ahead/free-behind... MADV_RANDOM or MADV_DONTNEED may be more useful... Or map the file in segments as you need them and unmap each segment before you need another one...

Comment: MADV_DONTNEED is exactly what I need. But I am afraid that the kernel may ignore it. If you mind to put it as an answer twalberg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For random read/write access to a `mmap()`ed file, `MADV_SEQUENTIAL` is probably not very useful (and may in fact cause undesired behavior). `MADV_RANDOM` or `MADV_DONTNEED` would be better options in this case. However, be aware that the kernel is free to ignore any `madvise()` - although in my understanding, Linux currently does not, as it tends to treat `madvise()` more as a command than an advisory...

Another option would be to `mmap()` only selected sections of the file as needed, and `munmap()` them as you're done with them, perhaps maintaining a pool of some small number of currently active mappings (i.e. mapping more than one region at once if needed, but still keeping it limited).

Answer (score 0):

Or course you must free resources when you're done with them in order not to leak them and thus run out of available space too soon.

Not sure what the question is, if you know about `mmap()` then surely you know about [`munmap()`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/munmap) too? It's right there on the same manual page.

Comment: Ah, I expressed myself incorrectly : I am not done with the file so don't want to call munmap. The file I am working on is approx 8Gb and i cannot split it. Will update the question accordingly :)